# Time complexity of iterating over a k-layer deep loop nest always Θ(nᵏ)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Many algorithms have loops in them that look like this:

```
for a from 1 to n
  for b from 1 to a
    for c from 1 to b
      for d from 1 to c
        for e from 1 to d
           ...
           // Do O(1) work
```

In other words, the loop nest is k layers deep, the outer layer loops from 1 to n, and each inner layer loops up from 1 to the index above it. This shows up, for example, in code to iterate over all k-tuples of positions inside an array.

Assuming that k is fixed, is the runtime of this code always Θ(n<sup>k</sup>)? For the special case where n = 1, the work is Θ(n) because it's just a standard loop over an array, and for the case where n = 2 the work is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) because the work done by the inner loop is given by

> 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n-1 = n(n-1)/2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Does this pattern continue when k gets large? Or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the time complexity will be Θ(n<sup>k</sup>). One way to measure the complexity of this code is to look at what values it generates. One particularly useful observation is that these loops will iterate over all possible k-element subsets of the array {1, 2, 3, ..., n} and will spend O(1) time producing each one of them. Therefore, we can say that the runtime is given by the number of such subsets. Given an n-element set, the number of k-element subsets is n choose k, which is equal to

> n! / k!(n - k)!

This is given by

> n (n-1)(n-2) ... (n - k + 1) / k!

This value is certainly no greater than this one:

> n · n · n · ... · n / k! (with k copies of n)
>
> = n<sup>k</sup> / k!

This expression is O(n<sup>k</sup>), since the 1/k! term is a fixed constant.

Similarly, when n - k + 1 ≥ n / 2, this expression is greater than or equal to

> (n / 2) · (n / 2) · ... · (n / 2) / k! (with k copies of n/2)
>
> = n<sup>k</sup> / k! 2<sup>k</sup>

This is Ω(n<sup>k</sup>), since 1 / k! 2<sup>k</sup> is a fixed constant.

Since the runtime is O(n<sup>k</sup>) and Ω(n<sup>k</sup>), the runtime is Θ(n<sup>k</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer. Glad you wrote this up.

Comment: You can also show this geometrically. Depth one corresponds to a line of length n. Depth two to the area of a triangle formed by adding a second line perpendicular to the first at the end(position n) and joining the end of it with a line to position one. Depth 3 to the volume of the pyramid formed by adding a line perpendicular to the prior line and joining it with lines to position one and n of the prior line. Depth 4 to the hyper volume of the hyper pyramid formed similarly, and so on. The volume of the k dimensional hyper pyramid grows as n to the k'th power.

Comment: Also, it isn't iterating over all k elt subsets. There's repetition. E.g., consider k>n. Granted, this doesn't affect the result for k fixed and n growing.

Comment: @DaveGalvin- That's a cool geometric intuition! Also, how does this loop nest include repetition? I'm not sure I see how that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You may consume the following equation:

[image]

Where **c** is the number of constant time operations inside the innermost loop, **n** is the number of elements, and **r** is the number of nested loops.